# Qt и Python: из TextEdit скопировать всё содержимое в буфер по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qclipboard

из `textEdit` при нажатии `pushButton_4` весь текст в буфер!

Пробовал через `pyperclip` - не робит!

```
def skopirovat ():
    pyperclip.copy(ui.textEdit.selectAll())


ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(skopirovat)
```

Comment: через import os тоже не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QClipboard Class
>
> Класс QClipboard обеспечивает доступ к буферу обмена оконной системы.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGridLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit,
                             QApplication, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QClipboard

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
   
        self.textEdit_1 = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit_1.insertPlainText("Используйте мышь для копирования текста в буфер обмена.\n"
                                        "Текст может быть скопирован из любого приложения.\n")
        self.textEdit_2 = QTextEdit()
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit_1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2, 0, 1)
        
        # Мы можем получить доступ к буферу, используя класс QClipboard. 
        # Затем мы можем вывести этот текст. 
        # Мы подключаем буфер обмена к методу, использующему строку:
        QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(self.clipboardChanged)
            
    # Получить содержимое системного буфера обмена
    def clipboardChanged(self):
        # Затем мы захватываем содержимое, используя:
        text = QApplication.clipboard().text()
        self.textEdit_2.insertPlainText(text + '\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    a_window.resize(700, 300)
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
def skopirovat ():
    cb = QApplication.clipboard()
    cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard)
    cb.setText(ui.textEdit.toPlainText(), mode=cb.Clipboard)


ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(skopirovat)
```

вот так работает)))